# VPN connection using Network Extension Framework iOS 8 in Swift not working

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to use the iOS 8 Network Extension Framework to setup a VPN connection when the users presses a UIButton. I've used the following tutorial: http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/. I also looked at this post [Can't setup VPN connection using Network Extension Framework iOS 8 in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562355/cant-setup-vpn-connection-using-network-extension-framework-ios-8-in-swift), which is the same behavior I am getting. When I run the app I get prompted for the vpn password and shared secret when installing the profile even though they were set with all the other required values in the code. And if I enter these details when installing the profile it still does not work. When trying to connect using the app it gives a "there's no sharedSecret" error. In the referenced post, the problem was apparently solved by rewriting the code that saves and accesses the keychain data in OBJ-C. I would like to get this to work in swift or understand why it does not work in swift.

This is the code for the connection

```
let manager = NEVPNManager.sharedManager()
@IBAction func connectToVpn(sender: AnyObject) {
  println("in call vpn")
           manager.loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
             if((error) != nil) {
                 println("VPN Preferences error: 1")
               }
              else {
                    var p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
                    p.username = "billy"
                    p.serverAddress = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
                    p.passwordReference = self.loadkeychain("vpnpassword")
                    println(p.passwordReference)
                    p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.SharedSecret
                    p.sharedSecretReference = self.loadkeychain("sharedSecret")
                    println(p.sharedSecretReference)
                    p.localIdentifier = "vpn"
                    p.remoteIdentifier = "vpn"
                    p.disconnectOnSleep = false
                    println("everything is set")
                    self.manager.`protocol` = p
                    self.manager.onDemandEnabled = true
                    self.manager.localizedDescription = "VPN"
                    self.manager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler({ (error) -> Void in
                        if((error) != nil) {
                            println("VPN Preferences error: 2")
                            println(error)
                        }
                        else {
                            var startError: NSError?
                            self.manager.connection.startVPNTunnelAndReturnError(&startError)
                            if((startError) != nil) {
                                println("VPN Preferences error: 3")
                                println(startError)}
                            else {
                                println("Start VPN")
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the code to save and retrieve from keychain

```
func savekeychain(key: String, value: String) -> Bool {
         let valueData = value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding,
            allowLossyConversion: false)
           let service = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!
                let secItem = [
                      kSecClass as! String :
                      kSecClassGenericPassword as! String,
                      kSecAttrService as! String : service,
                      kSecAttrAccount as! String : key,
                       kSecValueData as! String : valueData!,
        ]
           var result: Unmanaged<AnyObject>? = nil
            let status = Int(SecItemAdd(secItem, &result))
                switch status{
                  case Int(errSecSuccess):
                  println("Successfully stored the value")
                   case Int(errSecDuplicateItem):
                   println("This item is already saved. Cannot duplicate it")
        default:
            println("An error occurred with code \(status)")
        }
                return true
    }

    func loadkeychain(keyToSearchFor: String) -> NSData 
        let service = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!
         let query = [
          kSecClass as! String :
           kSecClassGenericPassword as! String,
            kSecAttrService as! String : service,
            kSecAttrAccount as! String : keyToSearchFor,
            kSecReturnData as! String : kCFBooleanTrue,
        ]
       var data: NSData!
        var returnedData: Unmanaged<AnyObject>? = nil
        let results = Int(SecItemCopyMatching(query, &returnedData))
         if results == Int(errSecSuccess){
              data = returnedData!.takeRetainedValue() as! NSData
               let value = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
               println("Value = \(value)")
                println("DATA = \(data)")
                    } else {
                  println("Error happened with code: \(results)")
        }
                     return data
    }
```

Ended up changing my functions that save and retrieve data from the keychain to OBJ-C methods as suggested by the referenced post and this did resolve the issues. Some testing indicated that both the swift and OBJ-C methods returned the same values, so I'm not sure why the swift methods cause the stated behavior. One other thing I noticed is that saving values to the keychain seems a little flaky, if you delete a key and then re-add it with a different value it seems to not work, requiring a reset of the keychain to the default. I still would like to figure out why the swift methods do not seem to work correctly.

Comment: How do If I want to setup a local VPN?

Answer (score 1):

I know i am late but it might help someone we need shared secret reference in `secItemCopyMatchig` you need add `kSecReturnPersistentRef` and set to true.
Below block helps you may be.

```
enum VPNKeychain {

    /// Returns a persistent reference for a generic password keychain item, adding it to
    /// (or updating it in) the keychain if necessary.
    ///
    /// This delegates the work to two helper routines depending on whether the item already
    /// exists in the keychain or not.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - service: The service name for the item.
    ///   - account: The account for the item.
    ///   - password: The desired password.
    /// - Returns: A persistent reference to the item.
    /// - Throws: Any error returned by the Security framework.

    static func persistentReferenceFor(service: String, account: String, password: Data) throws -> Data {
        var copyResult: CFTypeRef? = nil
        let err = SecItemCopyMatching([
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecReturnPersistentRef: true,
            kSecReturnData: true
            ] as NSDictionary, &copyResult)
        switch err {
        case errSecSuccess:
            return try self.persistentReferenceByUpdating(copyResult: copyResult!, service: service, account: account, password: password)
        case errSecItemNotFound:
            return try self.persistentReferenceByAdding(service: service, account:account, password: password)
        default:
            try throwOSStatus(err)
            // `throwOSStatus(_:)` only returns in the `errSecSuccess` case.  We know we're
            // not in that case but the compiler can't figure that out, alas.
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    /// Returns a persistent reference for a generic password keychain item by updating it
    /// in the keychain if necessary.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - copyResult: The result from the `SecItemCopyMatching` done by `persistentReferenceFor(service:account:password:)`.
    ///   - service: The service name for the item.
    ///   - account: The account for the item.
    ///   - password: The desired password.
    /// - Returns: A persistent reference to the item.
    /// - Throws: Any error returned by the Security framework.

    private static func persistentReferenceByUpdating(copyResult: CFTypeRef, service: String, account: String, password: Data) throws -> Data {
        let copyResult = copyResult as! [String:Any]
        let persistentRef = copyResult[kSecValuePersistentRef as String] as! NSData as Data
        let currentPassword = copyResult[kSecValueData as String] as! NSData as Data
        if password != currentPassword {
            let err = SecItemUpdate([
                kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                kSecAttrService: service,
                kSecAttrAccount: account,
                ] as NSDictionary, [
                    kSecValueData: password
                    ] as NSDictionary)
            try throwOSStatus(err)
        }
        return persistentRef
    }

    /// Returns a persistent reference for a generic password keychain item by adding it to
    /// the keychain.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - service: The service name for the item.
    ///   - account: The account for the item.
    ///   - password: The desired password.
    /// - Returns: A persistent reference to the item.
    /// - Throws: Any error returned by the Security framework.

    private static func persistentReferenceByAdding(service: String, account: String, password: Data) throws -> Data {
        var addResult: CFTypeRef? = nil
        let err = SecItemAdd([
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecValueData: password,
            kSecReturnPersistentRef: true,
            ] as NSDictionary, &addResult)
        try throwOSStatus(err)
        return addResult! as! NSData as Data
    }

    /// Throws an error if a Security framework call has failed.
    ///
    /// - Parameter err: The error to check.

    private static func throwOSStatus(_ err: OSStatus) throws {
        guard err == errSecSuccess else {
            throw NSError(domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain, code: Int(err), userInfo: nil)
        }
    }
}
```